# sql split yearly record into 12 monthly records

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to use common table expression to split an yearly record into 12 monthly records. I have to do it for next 20 years records . That means 20 rows into 600 rows (20*12=600 records).
What is the best way to do it.  Can anyone help with an efficient way to do it.
Using a single table as shown below. Year 0 means current year so it should split into remaining months and year=1 means next year onward it should split into 12 (months) records

```
id  year value
1   0   3155174.87
1   1   30423037.3
1   2   35339631.25
```

expected result should look like this:

Id  Year    Month   Value   Calender year
1   0   5   150 2022
1   0   6   150 2022
1   0   7   150 2022
1   0   8   150 2022
1   0   9   150 2022
1   0   10  150 2022
1   0   11  150 2022
1   0   12  150 2022
1   0   1   150 2023
1   0   2   150 2023
1   0   3   150 2023
1   0   4   150 2023
1   1   5   100 2023
1   1   6   100 2023
1   1   7   100 2023
1   1   8   100 2023
1   1   9   100 2023
1   1   10  100 2023
1   1   11  100 2023
1   1   12  100 2023
1   1   1   100 2024
1   1   2   100 2024
1   1   3   100 2024
1   1   4   100 2024

Comment: So what should the value be for each of the 12 rows for each year? Can you add your expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply join onto a list of months, and then use a bit of arithmetic to split the `Value`

```sql
SELECT
  t.Id,
  t.Year,
  v.Month,
  Value = t.Value / CASE WHEN t.Year = 0 THEN 13 - MONTH(GETDATE()) ELSE 12 END
FROM YourTable t
JOIN (VALUES
  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
) v(Month) ON t.year > 0 OR v.Month >= MONTH(GETDATE());
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=585525135685452610263c40b253251f)

Comment: Hello Charlieface,
Indeed this is one of the ways to achieve. Thanks for your quick response. Very helpful.

Comment: Hello Charlieface,
 I am trying to edit your query to achieve the below output:

Comment: Hello Charlieface,
 I am trying to edit your query to achieve the below output:
year 0 means: 12 records staring from next month (June 2022) till next 12 months(May 2023)
year 1 means: 12 records starting from June 2023 till May 2024. Could you please help

Comment: Probably something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f3ce7137104bac473f3a553f46d567ed

Comment: Hello @Charlieface, with your query YEAR 1 has again dates from June 2022, it should be from June 2023 and so on.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e174de8a088629bbda0f089ac09e4fb

Comment: Yes. this works. Incredible. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Charlieface,
One more challenge I am facing, probably you have an easy solution.
In your example code, suppose I need to divide first 6 lines (ie. for YEAR 0 the lines staring from MONTH  2022-06-30 to 2022-11-30 ) divide by 6 (value should be 525,862.478333) and then rest divide by 12, but the tricky part is that ,we need to divide (by 12) the value of subsequent year value . So in this case from 2022-12-31 to 2023-11-30 the value should be 2535253.108333 (value of year 1 divide by 12)  and so on

Comment: Not sure entirely what you mean. I suggest you create a new question for that

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I posted a new question. below is the link in case you want to have  a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72448055/sql-yearly-record-splitting-to-calculate-monthly-value

Comment: That is a terrible question, and unsurprising it got closed. You need to supply sample data (as **text**) and expecte results. And also your current attempt and a **clear** description of the problem. Note that deleting questions may not prevent you getting an automatic vote ban. i suggest you clean up that question and undelete it