# How to split single row yearly values into multi row monthly values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of values from yearly payments like this:

```
|   id   |   date   |  yearly_payment  |
| ------ | -------- | :--------------: |
| 1      | 06/01/21 | $600             |
| 2      | 06/01/22 | $720             |
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
|   id   |   date   |  monthly_payment  |
| ------ | -------- | :---------------: |
| 1      | 06/01/21 | $50               |
| 1      | 07/01/21 | $50               |
| 1      | ...      | $50               |
| 1      | 05/01/21 | $50               |
| 2      | 06/01/22 | $60               |
| 2      | 07/01/22 | $60               |
| 2      | ...      | $60               |
| 2      | 05/01/22 | $60               |
```

I thought I could achieve this through some transformation on a pivot table, but to no avail. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72381610/sql-split-yearly-record-into-12-monthly-records) gets me close, but I can't quite figure out how to achieve it within Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
select
  y.id, y.date + interval '1 month' * gs.a as date,
  y.yearly_payment / 12 as monthly_payment
from
  yearly_payments y
  cross join generate_series (0, 11) gs (a)
```

Beware of rounding...  if yearly_payment is an integer, then you would want to divide by 12.0 to force a numeric context.

Comment: You are a sage, thank you! Just for my own knowledge, what does the + interval '1 month' serve to do in this instance?

Comment: "interval" is a datatype in Postgres.  If you add an interval to a date or timestamp, it adds the specified amount of time to that date.  It's very diverse, so you can say "interval '2 years 3 months 4 seconds'" and it will work.  So I just took your date and added 0 months for the first record, 1 month for the second, 2 months for the third, etc.  Glad it worked for you.